# how to load string with special characters in to XElement?

Tags: linq-to-xml

I am trying to load an XML which has special characters such as ö and ® into XElement. But I get an error saying "Invalid character in the given encoding". Where do I set the encoding so that I will be able to load the string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could set the encoding in the first line of the XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

Could you show your XML file?

Comment: this is how the xml looks like


<page>
 <title>some title</title>
 <text pbname="body_text" pballowhtml="any"><![CDATA[<P>
<LI>OS Windows® 2000, Windows® XP Professional, Windows® XP Home Edition</LI>
</UL>]]></text>
 <a pbname="rss_link" href=""/>
 <text pbname="faq_catagories_field">Systems Integration</text>
</page>

i will try adding the xml encoding statement at the top. Thanks..

Comment: No sir adding the above line to the xml did not solve the issue.. :(

Comment: The XML looks valid and it loads fine with `XElement.Load("test.xml")`.

Comment: Now I saved the xml file with encoding statement in selecting the UTF-8 encoding. The file loaded up properly. but on writing it to a file, this is how the text came up

WindowsÂ® 2000

I capture the string from the read xml based on some logic and write it to a file with StreamWriter. How can I retain the proper characters..?

Comment: `new StreamWriter(stream, Encoding.UTF8)`

Comment: Hey thanks... here is the code for writing using (StreamWriter objStreamWriter = new StreamWriter(fileName,true,Encoding.UTF8,512))
                {
                    objStreamWriter.Write(fileContent);
                    objStreamWriter.Flush();
                    objStreamWriter.Close();
                }

Comment: Hey one more thing UTF-8 will not support text such as BÖWE  notice the Ö... its in CAPS how can that be considered?